# EC2 instance types for running a TitanDB cluster

Tags: amazon-ec2, cassandra, titan

I'm currently getting started on building up a graph database. For that I'm using Titan 1.0 and Cassandra 2.1.12 as the storage backend. For now I'll rely on Titans internal mechanisms for indexing and won't add any external indexing service like elasticsearch.

For the general surrounding the graph will be used in: For now the graph should mostly contain friendship and follower relations of my user base. Regarding read and write load I suspect some write load (e.g. when the user bulk-adds a lot of friends) and at the same time a lot of reads (e.g. the user wants a list of his friendships).

Today I ran some load tests and saw multiple times a spike in the metrics that Titan outputs.
[image]

I was wondering what kind of EC2 instances are best for running Titan? Right now I'm using r3.large but was wondering if maybe a little more CPU optimized instances would work better? Are there any benchmarks for different instance types out there?

Comment: When you say running Titan, can you clarify and provide details on what the load will be? Will the instance be read heavy or write heavy for example.

Comment: I edited my post above, long story short I'm expecting both but probably read will be a little more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the answer to your question is a little subjective I am going to point you in the direction of a post on [Performance Tuning Titan in AWS](https://blogs.aws.amazon.com/bigdata/post/Tx3JO46NGMX3WAW/Performance-Tuning-Your-Titan-Graph-Database-on-AWS). The post's author provides a comparison between the m4.large and m4.2xlarge with a Titan stack.

> As you can see, moving from a m4.large (2 vCPU, 8 GiB memory) instance
>   to an m4.2xlarge (8 vCPU, 32 GiB) only gives a 9% gain in performance
>   when running this particular query, which shows it isn’t bound by
>   memory or CPU.

He points out that having multiple instances running an individual service will allow for fine grained tuning. This will help you once the architecture is in production since the expected read/write percentages are unknown. I think splitting the services to specific instances is going to give you the freedom to tune the stack better than simply moving to a larger instance.

Comment: I was planning on a multi-machine cluster behind ELB anyways. Great link, thanks a lot!

Comment: Nevertheless, would you have any idea where from the spikes in execution time could come from? Really looks to me like some background mechanism doing something periodically since the load should have been pretty constant.

Comment: How are you administrating load tests? Spikes could happen if many edges are traversed by a given query or garbage collection is initiated by the JVM.